# How does one interpret the usda wholesale market price reports?

Tags: international-trade, commodities, agriculture

For example: http://www.ams.usda.gov/mnreports/nx_fv010.txt

The data for mangos is :
MANGOES:  MARKET STEADY.  flats 1 layer HT Francis (Francine) 9s 11.00 10s
12.00 12s 10.00-12.00 MX Keitt 7s 5.00-6.00 few 6.50 8s 5.00-6.00 few 6.50-7.00
9s 5.00-6.00 few 6.50 10s 5.00-6.00 few 6.50 12s 5.00 occas higher Kent 6s
6.00-7.00 fr appear 4.50 7s 5.00-6.00 8s 5.00-6.00 9s 5.00-6.00 10s 5.00-5.50
few 4.00 12s 5.00 Ataulfo 18s 12.00 25 lb cartons DR Banilejos 36.00

What exactly do these numbers mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MANGOES: MARKET STEADY. flats 1 layer [[*cargo type*]] HT [[*Haitii*]] Francis [[*variety*]] 9s [[*9 fruits in 1 layer flat*]] 11.00 [[*price for 9 fruits*]] 10s [[*10 fruits in 1 layer flat*]] 12.00 [[*price for 10 fruits*]] MX [[*Mexico*]] Keitt [[*Variety*]] 7s [[*count*]] 5.00-6.00 [[*price*]] few 6.50 [[*a few at a different price*]] ...etc... 25 lb cartons [[*cargo type*]] DR [[*dominican republic*]] Banilejos [[*variety*]] 36.00 [[*price*]]